# Adding string to item value of json array

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I am trying to list all my images from my uploads folder.

This is my php code :

```
public function listfiles()
{
    define('IMAGEPATH', 'uploads/');
    foreach(glob(IMAGEPATH.'*') as $filename){
        $imag[] =  basename($filename);
    }
    echo json_encode($imag);

}
```

I performed a ajax get request to my server this is my response :

```js
$.get( "http://test.dev/templates/listfiles", function( data ) {
    
    var host = 'http://test.dev/uploads/';
        $.each(JSON.parse(data), function( key, value ) {
      var images =[host + value];
      console.log(data);
          });
```

My Response :

```
["kkkk.jpg","test.jpg","test1.jpg"]
```

I am trying to add a string to my json array item value

want the output to be like this :

```js
      var host  'www.test.com/';
      
      var images = 
      [
      
      host + 'img/logo.png',
      host + 'img/tmp-blocks.jpg',
      host + 'img/tmp-tgl-images.jpg',
      host + 'img/tmp-send-test.jpg',
      host + 'img/tmp-devices.jpg',
      
      ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to change my code like this and it worked :

```
        define('IMAGEPATH', 'uploads/');
    foreach(glob(IMAGEPATH.'*') as $filename){
        $imag[] =  'http://cimailer.dev/uploads/'.basename($filename);
    }

    echo json_encode($imag,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

```js
    $.get( "http://cimailer.dev/templates/listfiles", function( data ) {
    
       var images =JSON.parse(data);
          
         });
```

Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 0):

First define `image` as an array and out of the loop, and then push concatenated string into `image` array.

```
$.get( "http://test.dev/templates/listfiles", function( data ) {      
    var host = 'http://test.dev/uploads/';
    var images =[];

    $.each(JSON.parse(data), function( key, value ) {
      images.push(host + value);
    });
    console.log(images);

})
```